# Sending arrays with Intent.putExtra

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, bundle

I have an array of integers in the activity A:

```
int array[] = {1,2,3};
```

And I want to send that variable to the activity B, so I create a new intent and use the putExtra method:

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
i.putExtra("numbers", array);
startActivity(i);
```

In the activity B I get the info:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int arrayB = extras.getInt("numbers");
```

But this is not really sending the array, I just get the value '0' on the arrayB. I've been looking for some examples but I didn't found anything so.

Comment: The answer I needed was in your question. It was how to use `.getExtras()` the I needed.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You are setting the extra with an array.  You are then trying to get a single int.

Your code should be:

```
int[] arrayB = extras.getIntArray("numbers");
```

Comment: Ouch! I was focused on the putExtra and getExtras syntax that i didnt realize the misstake was so obvious :D  Thank you!

Comment: @Kitinz +1 for to be very nice on community ... I liked that :)

Answer (score 9):

This code sends array of integer values

Initialize array List

```
List<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Add values to array List

```
test.add(1);
test.add(2);
test.add(3);
Intent intent=new Intent(this, targetActivty.class);
```

Send the array list values to target activity

```
intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("test", (ArrayList<Integer>) test);
startActivity(intent);
```

here you get values on targetActivty

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
ArrayList<String> test = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("test");
```

Answer (score -2):

```
final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "edit.list.message";

Context context;
public void onClick (View view)
{   
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,display.class);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.getParent();

    TextView textView = (TextView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String message = textView.getText().toString();

    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: i think you'll get to know after seeing this code that where u have done the mistake......:)