# How to send an ArrayAdapter to a ListActivity

Tags: android, listactivity, android-arrayadapter

i would like to know how to send an ArrayAdapter that i'm filling in one activity, to a ListActivity display it.

The program itself searches for bluetooth devices around and fills the ArrayAdapter with it's names, then i would like to sent the created list to a ListActivity so the user can select one.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Check this [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-to-pass-data-between-activities-in-android). It will be better not to send the ArrayAdapter via Intent but to send only the data (ArrayList or even String[]) and then to construct the ArrayAdapter in the new Activity.

Comment: thanks, I've created in the end the String[] and passed it in an intent. I was just wondering if it was possible to do the same with a ArrayAdapter directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848148/sending-information-with-intent-putextra) which explains how to pass a int[] across activities through `Intent.putExtra()`. Another option is that you would make the data that you want accessible by the other activity as `public static` so the other activity could just access it freely.