# How to send a String[] to another Activity?

Tags: android, string, send

In my app I need to send a

`String[] titlephotos;` to another Activity. I think that with Bundle it is not possible. How can I do this? Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sending arrays with Intent.putExtra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848148/sending-information-with-intent-putextra)

Use  `intent.putExtra(arrayvar);` in sending Activity

and

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
extras.getStringArray("numbers");
```

in the recipient activity.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using

```
public class SECOND_ACTIVITY extends LAST_ACTIVITY {...
```

you can use `static String s;`

if you are using

```
public class SECOND_ACTIVITY extends Activity{...
```

use this in fisrt activity:

```
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SECOND_ACTIVITY.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("STRING_NAME", VALUE_OF_STRING);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);}
```

call string in SECOND_ACTIVITY:

```
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();  
        STRING = extras.getString("STRING_NAME");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do several thins here, you can create a static field in the destination class and set the string array before launching the intent.

A nicer solution in my opinion is to create a singleton class to hold all variables you want to send between activitys. This is what i always did, if there is anyone with a nicer solution please tell.

Good luck!

[Wiki Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Edit: sorry ofcourse you can just use the standard bundle option, i read too quick and thought you were talking about custom objects! my bad

Answer (score 0):

Bundle does have a "putStringArray" method ...