# Data passing between two activities in android

Tags: android, android-activity, intentservice

Getting Value in Bundle but when placed that bundle value in string it is showing null value.here is my code:

Activity:1

```
    public void btnDeposite(View v)
{
     s1 = e1.getText().toString();
    amt1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);

    Intent i =new Intent(this,Transfer.class);
    i.putExtra("depositeAmount", amt1);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Activity:2

//in onCreate()

```
       b = getIntent().getExtras();
       s1 = b.getString("depositeAmount");
```

Comment: Please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8748539/2684 and you're passing an Integer btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Because you are changing  `amt1` into `int`

```
s1 = e1.getText().toString();
amt1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
```

and getting the value as a String

```
s1 = b.getString("depositeAmount");
```

Change it to

```
s1 = b.getInt("depositeAmount");
```

Hope this Helps.!!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
int s1 = b.getInt("depositeAmount");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `getString` with `getInt`

```
int s1 = b.getInt("depositeAmount");
```