# Display a city on long click in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am passing data between two activities. I want to do this: when the user long clicks on the map the new InfoActivity window opens, displaying latitude, longitude and the city where the longclick was made.

I already passed lat and long, but got stuck with the city part.

```
    @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), InfoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("latitude", arg0.latitude);
                intent.putExtra("longitude", arg0.longitude);
                startActivity(intent);

        }
```

How would I get the city where the map is long clicked and add pass it to my InfoActivity.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You might want to google for "reverse geocoding".

Comment: @Gerald Schenider Will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I get the city where the map is long clicked

Use [Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class with `arg0` for getting city where the map is long clicked.like:

```
 Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
 List<Address> allAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                               arg0.latitude, arg0.longitude, 1);
```

Now get all details from `allAddresses` which is required for long clicked point.

> and add pass it to my InfoActivity

For passing String between two Activities see following post:

[Passing strings between activities in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748444/passing-strings-between-activities-in-android)

Comment: I tried putting this code block in my onMapLongClick, but I get the following error for `Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());` - geocoder (android.content.context, Locale) in geocoder cannot be applied to (anonymous com.google.android.gms.maps.android maps.onmaplongclicklistener)

Comment: @Kemo: Use Your current Activity Context instead of `this ` like if you are using Activity then use `YourActivityName. this` or if using Fragment then use `getActivity()` instead of `this`

Comment: getActivity() worked. I also have another error - in `geocoder.getFromLocation(arg0.latitude, arg0.longitude, 1);` gets this error - unhandled exception java.ioexception, even if I tried:
                `try {
                    ArrayList<Address> allAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(arg0.latitude, arg0.longitude, 1);
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }`

Comment: without try/catch I get  unhandled exception java.ioexception, 

and with the try/catch I get incompatible types - required java.util.arrayList <Address> found java.util.array <Address>

Comment: @Kemo: Yes you need to wrap it inside `try/catch` block

Comment: I did wrap it in try catch/block but I got _incompatible types - required java.util.arrayList <Address> found java.util.array <Address>_ error

Comment: @Kemo: Use `List ` instead of `ArrayList`

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the Geocoder:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(arg0.latitude, arg0.longitude, 1);
String cityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
```