# Define TextView from ClassA in ClassB

Tags: java, android, string, textview

I have a TextView in ClassA.java :

```
TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
```

I want to use the value of this TextView in ClassB.java
How can i do this?

Comment: You're going to need to give us more info. Can you post ClassA and ClassB (or the relevant parts)? one way is to put a getTextView() method in ClassA and call it from ClassB

Comment: you need to share strings between activities

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing strings between activities in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748444/passing-strings-between-activities-in-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

To get String from TextView:

```
TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_id_here);
String text = txtView.getText().toString();
```

**Option A**
If you want to pass data through activities you can use putExtra().
Syntax (ClassA):

```
 @Override onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     ...
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, ClassB.class);   
     intent.putExtra("value", "Your text from TextView" );
```

Then, you have to get it in ClassB. 
Syntax:

```
Intent source = getIntent();
String textFromClassA = source.getStringExtra("value");
```

**Option B**
Initialize string as static and public.

```
public static String ...
```

Then you can easly access data from this variable.