# how to transfer string from autoCompleteTextView in one activity to others using set and get methods

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, autocompletetextview

[HELP]

please help me, what i want to do is, get String data from autoCompleteTextView and set it , then get String data in other activity

This is my AutoCompleteTextView code :

```
//autocomplete
    //Creating the instance of ArrayAdapter containing list of language names
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,dapilAuto);
    //Getting the instance of AutoCompleteTextView
    final AutoCompleteTextView actv= (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.nama_dapil);
    actv.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character
    actv.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView
    actv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    //ketika di pilih autocompletenya
    actv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selection = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            //String selection = actv.getText().toString();
            Dapil dapil = new Dapil(selection);
            dapil.setName_dapil(selection);

        }
    });
```

This is my get and set class :

```
 String name_dapil;



    public Dapil(){

    }

    public Dapil(String name_dapil){
        this.name_dapil = name_dapil;

    }

    public String getName_dapil() {
        return name_dapil;
    }
    public void setName_dapil(String name_dapil) {
        this.name_dapil = name_dapil;
    }
```

and This is how i get String data and implement it into cloud firestore to get document ID :

```
     Dapil dapil = new Dapil();
     String mDapil = dapil.getName_dapil();

     loadJumlahKursi(mDapil);




 private void loadJumlahKursi(String mDapil){

        DocumentReference kursiRef = firestoreDB.collection("perhitungansuara").document(mDapil);
        kursiRef.get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            DocumentSnapshot doc = task.getResult();
                            StringBuilder fields = new StringBuilder("");
                            fields.append("Jumlah Kursi: ").append(doc.get("jumlah_kursi"));
                            mJumlahKursi.setText(fields.toString());
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Gagal mendapatkan data:  ", task.getException());
                        }

                    }
                });
    }
```

and this is the issues

**02-06 18:18:27.700 5902-5902/com.example.erlangga.suaraku E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.erlangga.suaraku, PID: 5902
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.erlangga.suaraku/com.example.erlangga.suaraku.HasilActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Provided document path must not be null.
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2219)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Provided document path must not be null.
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq.checkNotNull(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.document(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.example.erlangga.suaraku.HasilActivity.loadJumlahKursi(HasilActivity.java:157)
                                                                                at com.example.erlangga.suaraku.HasilActivity.onCreate(HasilActivity.java:81)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2163)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)**

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Comment: @Piyush i'm sry edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the following Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Provided document path must not be null
```

because you are passing to the `document()` method the `mDapil` object which has the value of `null`. The reason is that the following line of code:

```
dapil.getName_dapil()
```

returns `null`.

If you want to pass `mDapil` between activities use an `Intent`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748444/passing-strings-between-activities-in-android) is how can be done.