# Initialising array passed from another activity

Tags: android, arrays, android-activity

I'm trying to pass a String array from one activity to another but when I try to read the array in the second activity, the values are null.

Here is how i'm passing the array from the first activity:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArray("Array", createArray(text));
Intent itemIntent = new Intent(this,Details.class); 
itemIntent.putExtra("passedArray", bundle);
startActivity(itemIntent);
```

createArray(text) is a method that returns an array.

Here's how i'm trying to read the array in the second activity:

```
Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();   
String[] array = extras.getStringArray("Array");
```

How do I initialise the array in the second activity with the corresponding array values that have been passed to it? If I try and read any of the values they have not been initialised and are null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use bundle try this and first calculate your array:

```
itemIntent.putExtra("passedArray", createArray(text));
startActivity(itemIntent);
```

And receive them as

```
 String[] array = this.getIntent().getStringArray("passedArray");
```

Comment: Had to use `Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();           
        String[] array = extras.getStringArray("passedArray");` to receive the array but apart from that it worked. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting the bundle containing your array within another extra.
That means you'd have to get the "passedArray" extra (which is a bundle) and then get your "Array" from the bundle that you just extracted. Instead change your code to this

```
Intent itemIntent = new Intent(this,Details.class); 
itemIntent.putExtra("Array", createArray(text));
startActivity(itemIntent);
```

Comment: If I use that I get the error message "The method putStringArray(String, String[]) is undefined for the type Intent" ?

Comment: Oops. I edited my answer to fix my error. It should just be putExtra

Answer (score 0):

I think you are messing around with bundle and extras. Look at this question. I think it can help you
[Sending arrays with Intent.putExtra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848148/sending-information-with-intent-putextra)