# how to use the single interface for listview click

Tags: android, android-intent

i am working on a app that has listview as the first activity. problem is that it is a question and answer app. whatever be the click(in the listview) the launching interface will be same the only difference will be questions And Answers(String from string array). problem is how to use a single intent that will help me differentiate between what was clicked in the listview so i could fetch the appropriate Q and A

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: maybe something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848148/sending-information-with-intent-putextra

Comment: @zapl thanks, looking forward to it

Comment: @dreamer1989 however you need to start a new activity, in this case a list activity similar to first one, but view is slightly different? Then the list adapter going to be differ, you can pass the currently selected list item with the intent.

Comment: @thujeevan sir, is there a tutorial on the same. as i am not able to get your point

Answer (score 2):

take this

```
v =(ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.cenima);
v.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) 
    {
    Log.i("position ", ""+position);
        //do samthing
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks,but it is not what i am looking for as  i am able to generate click and start new activity. problem is i want to use a single activity whatever is clicked on listview.