# Handle complex touch event

Tags: android, andengine

I'd like to draw a line after I touch the screen and stop moving, something like this "!MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN".

Thanks

Comment: did u want to drawing app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848148/sending-information-with-intent-putextra

Comment: no, just kind of move in my game. Sorry, but I don't get it :( You wanna say to send array of int or ...? :)

Comment: please improve your question. so far, i can only guess, what you need - i think it has to do with the pSceneTouchEvent.getMotionEvent() and the historical values, but as i said, it's only a guess

Comment: oh, sorry. Of course :) I'd like to draw a straight line. First x, y coordinates should be that where I touch the screen (so MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) and the second one should be that where I stop with moving (make some move on the screen and then when stop, but still touching the screen, draw a line). I hope it is usefull. Thanks :)