# Why Aren't Variable Values Passing between Activities?

Tags: android, string, variables, android-intent, android-activity

I'm a noob to android development and I am attempting to pass a variable between two classes.  According to my debugger, the value is being set in the first class, but for whatever reason it is returning null in the second class.  I initially tried passing the value by making the variable public and static and then I attempted placing the value in the Extras.  Both methods returned null in the second Activity. I have clean the project with no success. It seems as if it just won't won't allow the value of the string to be reset.  Any help resolving this is greatly appreciated.

My Code

CLASS A

```
case R.id.profile:      

        selection = (Integer)v.getTag();
        Log.e("Selection", String.valueOf(selection));

        if(LandingActivity.user_isClient){
            adapter_email = (listData.get(selection)).get("Email"); //<--debugger showing value as set here 
            Log.e("Adapter Email", adapter_email);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.tpssquared.kuttime.PROFILE_BARBER_VIEW");
            myIntent.putExtra("ADAPTER_EMAIL", adapter_email); //<--debugger showing value as set here too
            c.startActivity(myIntent);              
        }else{
            adapter_email = (listData.get(selection)).get("Client_Email"); //<--debugger showing value as set here
            Log.e("Adapter Email", adapter_email);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.tpssquared.kuttime.PROFILE_CLIENT_VIEW");
            myIntent.putExtra("ADAPTER_EMAIL", adapter_email); //<--debugger showing value as set here too
            c.startActivity(myIntent);  
        }

        break;
```

CLASS B

```
barber_email_string ="";//Deubugger showing value as null and not "". WHY?
try{
        if(barber_email_string.equals(null)||barber_email_string.equals("")){
            barber_email_string = getIntent().getStringExtra("ADAPTER_EMAIL");          

            if(barber_email_string.equals(null)||barber_email_string.equals("")){
                barber_email_string = Uri.encode(MyAppointments_ListAdapter.adapter_email);
                Log.e("BPV email",barber_email_string);
            }
        }
        Log.e("BPV email",barber_email_string);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("On Create", e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848148/sending-arrays-with-intent-putextra)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing a `Bundle` to Activity B, you're passing a `String` extra. So when you call `getExtras()`, there's nothing there. You can simply call `getStringExtra()` on the `Intent` itself to get your string.

```
barber_email_string = getIntent().getStringExtra("ADAPTER_EMAIL");
```

Alternatively, you *could* create a new `Bundle`, package the string into that, and pass it with `putExtras(myBundle)`, but that's overkill for a single string.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  However, I've tried your solution with no success.

Comment: Try putting that line of code directly after `super.onCreate()` to isolate it from your logic. If it logs correctly, then the problem isn't with retrieving the String.

Comment: Thanks.  That just helped me a great deal