# Get request code in started activity

Tags: android

after started new activity for result

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ContactActivity.class);        
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

how can i take requestCode in ContactActivity? i tried search in bundle but with no result

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
Utils.PrintInfo("requestCode : "+bundle.getInt("requestCode"));
```

Comment: In onActivityResult() method you can get your requestCode .

Comment: look into this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3848148/3326331)

Comment: yup in this case it is duplicate, i just had hope something changed