# How to pass values in sharedpreferences and store in array in new activity

Tags: android

I have one list of cities in listview.On click of list item i want to store this value in sharedpreferences and get in new activity.In this activity want to stare this values in array. I want to make a world Clock given in every devices.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Use intent.putextra() to pass the values from activity to another. Do not use shared preference in this case.

Comment: This answer will help you. 

**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848148/sending-arrays-with-intent-putextra**

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about using `SharedPreferences` is that they are globally accessible within the context of your application - you do not need to "pass" them around. Furthermore, you can handle this nicely with the `putStringSet` method of `SharedPreferences`. In your `onClick` method, simply save your cities as follows:

```
Set<String> cityList = new HashSet<String>();
cities.add("City1");
cities.add("City2");
// Repeat for all cities in your list...
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("yourPreferences", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences .edit();
editor.putStringSet("cityList", cityList);
editor.commit();
```

Then, when you wish to retrieve the cities in your new `Activity`, simply use the following code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("yourPreferences", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
Set<String> cityList = sharedPreferences.getInt("cityList", new Set<String>());
```