# How do I create, pass and add values to an int array in my activities

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, android-activity

I'm new in programming and I recently encountered a problem in activities. I couldn't pass my int array to multiple activities.

Here is my First Activity :

```
 public void Start(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Situation1.class);
    i.putExtra("arr", new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0});
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Here is my Situation1:

```
 public void Serious(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Situation2.class);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    int[] arr = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("arr");
    arr[2]=arr[2]+1;
    arr[1]=arr[1]+1;
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Situation2:

```
public void India(View view)
    {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Situation3.class);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle b = i.getExtras();
    int[] arr=i.getIntArrayExtra("arr");
    arr[0]=arr[0]+1;
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In Situation1 and Serious function, you didn't put your array in intent which you start the next activity with.

```
public void Serious(View view)
{
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Situation2.class);
Intent i = getIntent();
int[] arr = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("arr");
arr[2]=arr[2]+1;
arr[1]=arr[1]+1;
intent.putExtra("arr", arr);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: How do I do that? Thank you for the immediate response!

Answer (score 0):

You can use arraylist of integer like this:

This code sends array of integer values

Initialize array List

```
List<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Add values to array List

```
test.add(1);
test.add(2);
test.add(3);
Intent intent=new Intent(this, targetActivty.class);
```

Send the array list values to target activity

```
intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("test", (ArrayList<Integer>) test);
startActivity(intent);
```

here you get values on targetActivty

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
ArrayList<String> test = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("test");
```

For more information:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848148/sending-arrays-with-intent-putextra](http://link)

Answer (score 0):

While passing:

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putIntArray("arr", new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0});
Intent i = new Intent(this, Situation1.class);
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
```

While getting (most probably in `oncreate` of `Situation1` activity):

```
Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
int[] array=b.getIntArray("arr");
```