# How to view string of email addresses android

Tags: android

help anyone

I can't figure this out

```
String [] manager = {"String", "String", "String", "String", "String", 
"String", "String"};

String [] supervisors = {"String","String", "String", "String"};

email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String [] {String.valueOf(manager)});
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String [] {String.valueOf(supervisors)});
```

I want to show it like this: `someone@example.com`

but all I get is `[Ljava.lang.String]`

Comment: Try this : email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, manager);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending arrays with Intent.putExtra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848148/sending-arrays-with-intent-putextra)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
String [] manager = {"String", "String", "String", "String", "String", 
"String", "String"};

String [] supervisors = {"String","String", "String", "String"};

email.putExtra("managerarray",manager);
email.putExtra("supervisors", supervisors);
```

While fetching in Another **Activity**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String [] managerarray = intent.getStringArrayExtra("managerarray");
String [] supervisors = intent.getStringArrayExtra("supervisors");
```

Comment: will try that ty

Comment: @AppDevelopment what i'm not getting???......If my answer is really usefull please donot forgot to upvote